# Spring Boot + SSL : Consuming Too much CPU

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot

I tested the performance of Java Spring framework with features like Spring Boot + SSL to develop REST API.

I found out that if I add SSL feature to Spring framework, it would consume too much CPU. However, I remove SSL feature, this problem won`t happen.

I did the stress test either by sending current 20 HTTP requests/sec or 100 requests/sec to test REST application, the application would always consume nearly 200% of CPU.

I have changed the application services from Spring to Tomcat. The result was the same.

```
Test Environment
 - Sender  : Loading Test Generator Ubuntu, Dual Core, EC2 on AWS.
 - Receiver: Spring-Boot + SSL, Ubuntu, Dual Core, EC2 on AWS.
```

The following is the test program on receiver server.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

The following are Loading Test Generator commands in siege on sender server.

```
 //Current 1 request 
 siege -b -c6 -t60S https://receiver Server IP:8443/ 

 //Current 100 request 
  siege -b -c100 -t60S https://receiver Server IP:8443/
```

The following info is my test result on receiver server.

```
Current Requests/sec     Usage of CPU1  Usage of CPU2    Succ
   1                         40%           40%           100%
   2                         80%           80%           100%
   3                         95%           95%           100%
   6                         100%          100%          100%
  100                        100%          100%          100%
  600                        100%          100%          100%
```

It seems that the maximum performance of Spring is 3 requests/sec while the usage of CPU is below 100%. Although the spring app can process all the requests, it consumes too much CPU.

Please download a very simple code as below and give it a try. 
https://github.com/dpomaresp/Spring-boot-with-ssl

Could you help me to clarify this issue ? Why has this strange issue occurred ? Is it an issue of Spring framework ?

Your kindly assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: I also have tested it with Spring-boot  framework v1.3.0 and 1.4.0. The result was the same.

Comment: You don't add ssl to spring you add it to tomcat. So changing it from embedded to non embedded shouldn't change a thing. Ofcourse it will increase cpu load as encryption and decryption is taking place for all connections.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I did add it to Tomcat. But the cpu load was increased too fast even sending a small amount of data to REST application.

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? Or you stopped after the first sentence? SSL will add overhead as everything needs to be encrypted/decrypted. So yes it adds cpu load. How much depends on your system. Testing those things locally is probably not representative for the real production system.

Comment: I did. I knew it would add overhead on CPU because of encryption or decryption. But it was abnormal. If the REST application was developed by C/C++, the cpu might be increased gradually. I did not test on local system, but on different servers - the sender using the stress tool was installed on server A and receiver, REST app, was set up on server B. It should simulate the real Users using the REST API. I want to know why this problem occurred and how to improve it.

Comment: What does your Tomcat SSL configuration look like?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I did the test on Spring-Boot and Tomcat. 
The result was the same. 
My configuration file of Tomcat is shown below.

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Service name="Catalina">
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="conf/keystore.p12"
               keystorePass="XXXXX" />

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Downgrading tomcat worked for me.
See http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/High-CPU-Consumption-with-Tomcat-8-5-4-NIO-and-SSL-td5054445.html